# How to make English text render right-to-left in mixed RTL <pre> tag?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, pre

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .rtl {
      direction: rtl;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="rtl">
שלום עולם <b>Right Text</b> ..... <b>Left Text</b> חמש
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xq809b4g/2/

Currently it renders "LeftText" left to שלום עולם, and "RightText" right to "חמש".

Usually, this makes sense, because when I embed English text in RTL text, I'd usually want it to display the English sentence Left-to-Right. However, in this case, because I'm writing a table of contents - The subjects should appear on the right, and the authors should appear on the left.

Can I make it render the opposite way, while still keeping the `<pre>` tag? In other words, "Right Text" should appear left to "שלום עולם", and "Left Text" right to "חמש".

Current State:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the use of **dir** attribute.

When using *dir* attribute, you can use these values:

**ltr**, which means left to right and is to be used for languages that are written from the left to the right.

**rtl**, which means right to left and is to be used for languages that are written from the right to the left.

**auto**, which lets the user agent decide. It uses a basic algorithm as it parses the characters inside the element until it finds a character with a strong directionality, then applies that directionality to the whole element.

```html
<pre dir="auto">
  שלום עולם <b dir="ltr">RightText</b> ..... <b dir="ltr">LeftText</b> חמש
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Newbee's excellent answer, adding an `&rlm` character before and after the dots allows mid-sentence changing of the direction of the text.

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<pre class="rtl">
שלום עולם <b>Right Text</b> &rlm;.....&rlm; <b>Left Text</b> חמש
</pre>
```