# Join function is not working in right-to-left environment

Tags: javascript

I have one issue with my javascript code where I'm using join function.
I have this object.

```
const temp = {
    "sub": "اختبار تشتيت الانتباه",
    "dpt": "الجبيل",
    "work": "المنطقة الشرقية",
    "test": "6935",
    "Vspec": "Test Value"
}
```

when I'm doing this:-> [temp.sub, temp.test].join(", ") it is producing different output where temp.test number is getting appended first.

when I'm using this: [temp.sub, temp.test].join(", ") then output should be temp temp.sub first & then temp.test.

```js
const temp = {
    "sub": "اختبار تشتيت الانتباه",
    "dpt": "الجبيل",
    "work": "المنطقة الشرقية",
    "test": "6935",
    "Vspec": "Test Value"
};

console.log([temp.sub, temp.test].join(", "));
```

kindly help. Thanks

Comment: *"...where temp.test number is getting appended first."* Define "first." Remember that you're dealing with a right-to-left language. So the 6935 would be displayed to the *left* of the Arabic you're joining it to, which is *after* it from an RTL perspective.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, output which is coming is :- `6935 اختبار تشتيت الانتباه` expected output is opposite of the mentioned word. but suppose the value is Vspec(which is english) the it is coming properly. how can I solve this?

Comment: @mplungjan cool, that's pretty much solves the answer but how to use it with join function?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76031860/how-to-make-english-text-render-right-to-left-in-mixed-rtl-pre-tag Re @mplungjan's example of using the LRM with `join`, beware that it's specific to the situation where you have LTR text in the first element and RTL text in the second. Fundamentally, `join` is problematic when joining text that works in different directions, the template literal he showed initially is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the Left-to-Right Mark (LRM) Unicode character `\u200E`:

```js
const temp = {
    "sub": "اختبار تشتيت الانتباه",
    "dpt": "الجبيل",
    "work": "المنطقة الشرقية",
    "test": "6935",
    "Vspec": "Test Value"
};

console.log([temp.sub, temp.test].join(", ")); // original

console.log(`${temp.sub}\u200E, ${temp.test}`);  // template literals (safest)

console.log([temp.sub, temp.test].join(",\u200E ")); // LRM before the comma join

console.log([temp.sub, temp.test].join("\u200E, ")); // LRM after the comma join
```